# Print list in R without loops (apply)

Tags: r, apply, lapply

I hope that, this question will be nice tutorial for beginners in R (such as me).
I was used to programming languages where loops are necessary to manipulate the data, algorithms, etc.
Nevertheless, loops in R are slow, what can be seen in case of large data.
Fortunately R provides bulit-in functions which allow to iterating through elements and do some calculation in very efficient way.

Now I'd like to avoid loops when I'm analysying data in R. So I've read about **lapply**, **apply** and other useful functions.

I'd like to make correlation between first and each other column of my data and print: sample name, sample estimate and p-value in nice table - everything without **for loop**.

**My idea** - create fake data from stratch:

```
surv <- c(7.1,8,4,2,0.5,5,6)
geneA_expr <- runif(n = 7, min = 1, max = 30)
geneB_expr <- runif(n = 7, min = 1, max = 30)
geneC_expr <- runif(n = 7, min = 1, max = 30)
my_data <- data.frame(surv, geneA_expr, geneB_expr, geneC_expr)
```

Correlation test with **apply** - found it here in Stack Overflow and in manual:

```
md_stat <- apply(my_data[,2:4], 2, cor.test, my_data$surv, method="pearson")
```

md_stat is a list, now I'd like to visualize it nicely, but I have no idea how to do it, it's too complicated for me, so I used **for loop**

```
for(i in names(md_stat)){
  cat(i ,md_stat[[i]]$estimate, md_stat[[i]]$p.value, '\n')
}

geneA_expr 0.2517658 0.5860052 
geneB_expr 0.2438112 0.5982849 
geneC_expr 0.8026801 0.02977544
```

**How to replace above for loop by other bulit-in function?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unlist` every list within `md_stat`. then bind the outputs into a matrix.

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(md_stat, unlist))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
temp <- lapply(seq_along(md_stat), function(i) {
    cat(names(md_stat)[[i]], md_stat[[i]]$estimate, md_stat[[i]]$p.value, '\n')
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I can think of 4 ways for you to do this, 1 of which depends on the purrr package.

You could use a loop, walk from the purrr package, lapply and a recursive function.

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(purrr)

surv <- c(7.1,8,4,2,0.5,5,6)
geneA_expr <- runif(n = 7, min = 1, max = 30)
geneB_expr <- runif(n = 7, min = 1, max = 30)
geneC_expr <- runif(n = 7, min = 1, max = 30)
my_data <- data.frame(surv, geneA_expr, geneB_expr, geneC_expr)

md_stat <- apply(my_data[,2:4], 2, cor.test, my_data$surv, method="pearson")


md_loop <- function(md_stat) {
  for(i in names(md_stat)){
    cat(i ,md_stat[[i]]$estimate, md_stat[[i]]$p.value, '\n')
  }
}

md_walk <- function(md_stat) {
  walk(names(md_stat), function(i) {
    cat(i ,md_stat[[i]]$estimate, md_stat[[i]]$p.value, '\n')
  })
}

md_apply <- function(md_stat) {
  lapply(names(md_stat), function(i) {
    cat(i[[1]],md_stat[[i[[1]]]]$estimate, md_stat[[i[[1]]]]$p.value, '\n')

  })
}

md_recursive <- function(md_stat) {
  i <- names(md_stat)

  if(length(i) < 1) {
    NULL
  } else {
    cat(i[[1]],md_stat[[i[[1]]]]$estimate, md_stat[[i[[1]]]]$p.value, '\n')
    md_recursive(tail(md_stat, -1))
  }
}

md_speed <- microbenchmark(
  md_loop(md_stat),
  md_walk(md_stat),
  md_apply(md_stat),
  md_recursive(md_stat)
)
```

Speed comparisons
[image: microbenchmark]